# "Lazy Drawing" of UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, uicollectionview, lazy-evaluation

This question isn't about lazy loading of images, I can do that no problem. What I have here is an issue where each cell has complex drawing of gradients, etc, which causes the collectionView to noticeably stutter as each cell is drawn (when scrolling more quickly). What I'd like to do is somehow draw only when scrolling slowly or when the user stops scrolling. I tried doing all the drawing using NSOperationQueue (& cancelling when the cell went off screen) but it was worse than ever.

If anyone has any advice about a good approach, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the approach from `Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS` from `WWDC 2012`? They show a similar example and explain how to move drawing to the background thread.

Comment: That was great - I was on the right track already, but the example let me refine it & get it working well